# Why this code error in my code?(android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My codeError!

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.uni_cob"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 33
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```